# how can i remove the index.php form the url of Codeigniter 3.1.9

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have Changed the

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and in `.htaccess` I have written this code. but the `index.php` cannot remove from the `URL`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Another option is to set Routes  from the config folder.... where you can set the url what you want & redirect to actual url which start from index.php/controller_name/function name

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Have you set the base URL?

Comment: Using Routes : $route['my-controller/log-in']  =  'index.php/logincontroller/login'; [remove base url index.php]

Comment: Using htaccess : check in apache config.... folder allowed or not [remove base url index.php]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `base_url` to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/base_folder/
```

Use this `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /base_folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```